# Is it possible to write an indexed type where the key is the discriminating property of a discriminating union and the value is the union member

Tags: typescript

I have types like these:

```
type Cat = {sound: 'Meaow', species: 'cat'}
type Dog = {sound: 'Woff', species: 'dog'}

type Animal = Cat | Dog
```

I want to write a "registry" for species that enforces every species to be associated with their discriminating key:

So, something like this (TS does not allow this syntax)

```
type RegisteredAnimals<T extends Animal> = { [key: T['species'] ]?: T}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// types allow only on Animal with given spec
type WithTheSpecies<T extends Animal, Spec extends Animal['species']> = 
T extends { species: Spec } ? T : never;
// mapped type which has key as spec, and value only type with exactly that spec
type RegisteredAnimals<T extends Animal = Animal> = 
{ [K in T['species']]?: WithTheSpecies<T, K> }

// using
const reg: RegisteredAnimals = {
  cat: { sound: 'Meaow', species: 'cat' },
  dog: { sound: 'Woff', species: 'dog' },
}
```

### Explanation

We need mapped type which will ensure that we use only species keys `K in T['species']`, but also we need to ensure that the value at given key is an object which has this species value. The first type is visible here as `RegisteredAnimals` and the second type as `WithTheSpecies`.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not only that. If I do it like this, then when I use the `RegisteredAnimals` type it requires that I provide a type variable, which is exactly the opposite of what I want.

Comment: So you dont need an argument then. Let me update the answer

Comment: @loxs check the second version. It works with the type `Animal` itself

Comment: This doesn't enforce that the key and the value are related (it should only allow 'cat' for key when the value is of type `Cat`)

Comment: Ok check the answer now

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to make your code compile. `const reg` does not accept the provided object.

Comment: playground - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsKBeKBvAzgewK4DsAmAXFAOQCyEcmA7iQDRTqQDGAlhOsScwiQL4AoUJCgARTAHNkaLHiKkA6pgBmy+oxbtOpfJP4Ch4aAEFcrALZwANtPiIAPmMkHh0Ba2AALACqeIAZU0OAB5vKAgAD2AIAnQoUwtrBkCIZnComPw4hMsrAG0SJlStEgBdAD5pMMjo2LQNYo5iFLS+KAB+KDDiXAgANwgAJwBuQxEAJQgJVnRowYh8HOt0UPTarPizXOklq0qUVCg8gGkoVlwugqK2DjLS9uJ3L18AoJXvBmPKwQFmTFxZlB5hJiJNprMhgtdnEDgIoFAeMBiIdZAQuBQqLQGNctFxESQoHw6HCoLoQfVUfISEpVOocU0dHpCcS+EA

Comment: Instead of the `WithTheSpecies` helper, you can use `Extract<T, {species: K}>`.

Comment: Instead of a default type param for `RegisteredAnimals` that should never be provided by the user, I would do `type RegisteredAnimals = _RegisteredAnimals<Animal>`, where `_RegisteredAnimals` is the main type.